# Error using instagram-node

Tags: node.js, instagram

This is my code run on a node.js server. I have the proper access token obtained from OAuth2.0 protocol as defined in the Instagram developer page.

```
function getMedia(accessToken) {
    var instagram = require('instagram-node').instagram();
    instagram.use({
      access_token: accessToken
    });
    instagram.user_self_media_recent(function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(medias);
    });
}
```

I'm getting this in my error response:

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.instagram.com api.instagram.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.instagram.com',
  host: 'api.instagram.com',
  port: 443,
  retry: [Function: retry] }
```

Does anyone know what this error response means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick follow up. I was using Google's Firebase for my backend. On the "Spark" plan you get this warning:

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and
>   quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these
>   restrictions

I upgraded to "Blaze" plan and now retrieve data from Instagram.

The answer posted below suggests that I need to initialize the Instagram client with a client_id and client_secret, this is not true. I am getting media posts with just the access_token.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the instagram client you should use your app's client Id and client secret.

```
instagram.use({
  client_id: INSTA_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: INSTA_CLIENT_SECRET,
});
```

Then use the access token you have to authenticate the specific instagram user and request medias on their behalf.

```
instagram.use({
  access_token: accessToken
});
instagram.user_self_media_recent(function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(medias);
});
```

When you first initialize your instagram node client you must use the authentication credentials that you receive from instagram when you register your app [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/).

Comment: Got it working. No need to initialize with client_id and client_secret, accessToken is sufficient enough.